# Can setup include_requires circumvent the best match in PyPI and clone the repo?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py, install-requires

The master branch of [SHAP](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/commit/fc30c661339e89e0132f5f89e5385e3681090e1f) fixes a clash with XGBoost, which is not fixed in the latest PyPI version: `0.35.0`. Both SHAP and XGBoost are included in the list for `install_requires` in `setup`. I have tried the following (and many variants):

`'shap @ git+ssh://git@github.com/slundberg/shap/fc30c661339e89e0132f5f89e5385e3681090e1f#egg=shap'`,

but they all result in `Best match shap 0.35.0`. Hence, the setup uses `Processing shap-0.35.0.tar.gz`, and the egg has the same clash between SHAP and XGBoost.

Without `setup` I have tested  `pip install git+https://github.com/slundberg/shap.git#egg=shap`, and it retrieves the branch without the clash. Trying to use `'git+ssh://github.com/slundberg/shap.git#egg=shap'` results in `'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers`

Is there a suitable fix with setup that does not require waiting for a new SHAP release on PyPI?

Comment: @phd that does not solve the question... I have already upgraded setuptools.

Comment: "*'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers*" means your `pip` and `setuptools` are too old and nothing else.

Comment: @phd I'm using version: 20.1.1 of pip and 49.2.0 of setuptools. You missed the point of the question.